# How to save of the current state of a notebook in JupyterLab

Tags: python, html, jupyter-lab, nbconvert

I would like to export a JupyterLab notebook (not Jupyter Notebook) to HTML.

I am using the following code inside of the notebook itself, that correctly exports the notebook:

`os.popen('jupyter nbconvert current_notebook.ipynb --to html').read()`

However, nbconvert is not getting current notebook but the last saved state, on disk, of the notebook.

So, I need to save the state before trying to export it.

I am trying to use the following code:

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.save_notebook()
```

But apparently JupyterLab does not support JS API, so it is returning the following message:

`Javascript Error: IPython is not defined`

Do you know a way to save the current state of the notebook before exporting it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's a fresh notebook and you run it from top to bottom, you can use the following command in the last cell:

```
import os
%notebook -e test.ipynb
os.system('jupyter nbconvert --to html test.ipynb')
```

It will give a `test.html` file.

Or, you can use javascript and HTML to emulate the CTRL + s event,

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

### emulate Ctrl + s
script = """
this.nextElementSibling.focus();
this.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {key:'s', keyCode: 83, ctrlKey: true}));
"""
display(HTML((
    '<input style="width:0;height:0;border:0">'
).format(script)))

import os

os.system('jupyter nbconvert --to html test.ipynb') # here, test is the name of your notebook
```

Now, `keyCode: 83` this line can change based on your OS. If you are in windows, 83 should do, else you may have to check the keycode for 's', the easiest way I found was to go to this website http://keycode.info/ and type `s`.

ref: https://unixpapa.com/js/key.html